# How do I set this value for selenium selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");?

Tags: selenium

I'm using selenium and I need to change or make sure my instance of selenium is  using this XPath library. Where do I configure the line selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");? Which file is it in order is it in?

Answer (score -1):

This is a new feature added to Selenium. I just had to get the latest version and then I was able to access it through the .NET API.